# Adjust variable height in formula

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath

I want to write the following expression

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amstext} 

\begin{document}
This formula is very important: $\frac{X_{ij}}{X_{ji}}\frac{X_{ii}}{X_{jj}}$
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the `$X_{ij}$` is higher than the `$X_{ii}$`

How can I adjust the height of both variables to be equally high?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\frac{X_{ii\vphantom{j}}}{X_{jj}` should do the trick. Actually this does not happen with displaystyle fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the instruction `\vphantom{j}` to the subscript in question:

```
$\frac{X_{ij}}{X_{ji}}\frac{X_{ii\vphantom{j}}}{X_{jj}}$
```

A `\vphantom`, or "vertical phantom", has the height and depth as its argument, but no width -- and is therefore invisible.